# Responsive DataTable causing weird select box bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a [DataTable](https://datatables.net) and I am also using the [responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) for it.

In my DataTable, there is a select box and when you change the select box there is a prompt asking if you are sure you want to make this change. On normal mode, it works fine, but when it is responsive it doesn't work. The pop-up dialogue gives the wrong values of the data to be changed. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    responsive: true
  });
});

function changeResStatus(str1) {
  var id = str1;
  var status = document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value;
  var mailres = "";
  var r = confirm("Change status for ID # " + id + " to " + status + "?");
  if (r == true) {
    alert("changed!");
  } else {
    alert("not changed!");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>BUG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>
        <select id="resstatus1" data-previousvalue="audi" onchange="changeResStatus(1);">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option selected value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>
        <select id="resstatus2" data-previousvalue="audi" onchange="changeResStatus(2);">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option selected value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Super weird behavior, how can I fix this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `event.target.value` to get the selected value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    responsive: true
  });
});

function changeResStatus(str1) {
  var id = str1;
  var status = document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value;
  var mailres = "";
  var r = confirm("Change status for ID # " + id + " to " + event.target.value + "?");
  if (r == true) {
    alert("changed!");
  } else {
    alert("not changed!");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>BUG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>
        <select id="resstatus1" data-previousvalue="audi" onchange="changeResStatus(1);">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option selected value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>
        <select id="resstatus2" data-previousvalue="audi" onchange="changeResStatus(2);">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option selected value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```